# Not in scope data constructor

Tags: haskell

I have two .hs files: one contains a new type declaration, and the other uses it.

first.hs:

```
module first () where
    type S = SetType
    data SetType = S[Integer]
```

second.hs:

```
module second () where
    import first
```

When I run second.hs, both modules first, second are loaded just fine.

But, when I write `:type` S on Haskell platform, the following error appears

> Not in scope : data constructor 'S'

*Note: There are some functions in each module for sure, I'm just skipping it for brevity*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
module first () where
```

Assuming in reality the module name starts with an upper case letter, as it must, the empty export list - `()` - says the module doesn't export anything, so the things defined in `First` aren't in scope in `Second`.

Completely omit the export list to export all top-level bindings, or list the exported entities in the export list

```
module First (S, SetType(..)) where
```

(the `(..)` exports also the constructors of `SetType`, without that, only the type would be exported).

And use as

```
module Second where

import First

foo :: SetType
foo = S [1 .. 10]
```

or, to limit the imports to specific types and constructors:

```
module Second where

import First (S, SetType(..))
```

You can also indent the top level,

```
module Second where

    import First

    foo :: SetType
    foo = S [1 .. 10]
```

but that is ugly, and one can get errors due to miscounting the indentation easily.

Comment: yes, it stars with capital letters(i just forgot to write it here that way)
where to write the import line then ?

Comment: Yes, wouldn't have compiled otherwise.

Comment: where to write the import First line, so that its data types are in Second's scope ?

Comment: The imports come directly after the module declaration. The indentation used for them determines the indentation for the module, typically, one would use no indentation for the top-level. So `module Second where\n\nimport First\n\n...`. (The `\n` shall be actual newlines)

Answer (score 3):

- Module names start with a capital - Haskell is case sensitive
- Line up your code at the left margin - layout is important in Haskell.
- The bit in brackets is the export list - miss it out if you want to export all the functions, or put everything you want to export in it.

`First.hs`:

```
module First where

type S = SetType
data SetType = S[Integer]
```

`Second.hs`:

```
module Second where
import First
```