# What does (..) mean?

Tags: haskell, cardano

I'm trying to learn Haskell.

I'm reading the code on here[1]. I just copy and past some part of the code from lines:46 and 298-300.

**Question**: What does (..) mean?

I Hoggled it but I got no result.

```
module Pos.Core.Types(
-- something here

 SharedSeed (..) -- what does this mean?

) where


newtype SharedSeed = SharedSeed
{ getSharedSeed :: ByteString
} deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Generic, NFData, Typeable)
```

---

[1] https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-sl/blob/master/core/Pos/Core/Types.hs

Comment: [Relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13481892/752976)

Comment: For anybody else landing on this question via the search engine: `..` also has *another*, unrelated meaning in lists: `[1..5]`. Here it's syntax sugar for `enumFromTo`. You can probably find out about this if you search for "list comprehensions".

Comment: Not just `enumFromTo`: that whole family of Enum functions have shorthand notations using `..` in different ways.

Answer (score 5):

It means "export all constructors and record fields for this data type".

When writing a module export list, there's three<sup>4</sup> ways you can export a data type:

```
module ModuleD(
    D,       -- just the type, no constructors
    D(..),   -- the type and all its constructors
    D(DA)    -- the type and the specific constructor
    ) where

data D = DA A | DB B
```

If you don't export any constructors, the type, well, can't be constructed, at least directly. This is useful if you e.g. want to enforce some runtime invariants on the data type:

```
module Even (evenInt, toInt) where

newtype EvenInt = EvenInt Int deriving (Show, Eq)

evenInt :: Int -> Maybe EvenInt
evenInt x = if x `mod` 2 == 0 then Just x else Nothing

toInt :: EvenInt -> Int
toInt (EvenInt x) = x
```

The caller code can now use this type, but only in the allowed manner:

```
x = evenInt 2
putStrLn $ if isJust x then show . toInt . fromJust $ x else "Not even!"
```

---

As a side note, `toInt` is usually implemented indirectly via the record syntax for convenience:

```
data EvenInt = EvenInt { toInt :: Int }
```

<sup>4</sup> See [**@leftaroundabout**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45460532/752976)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if we don't use it?

Comment: @user153438 Then only the type itself is exported, but users can't see the constructors. It's an abstract type.

Comment: @melpomene thanks. Am I right it can still use the constructor?

Comment: @user153438 I've added an example, hope it clarifies things a bit.

Comment: _export all constructors for this data type_ ← not only constructors, record fields as well.

Comment: In general, you should either export *all* the constructors or *none* of them. The same syntax is used for class methods. It can make sense to (re-)export only some class methods.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of import/export lists has not much to do with the syntax of Haskell itself. It's just a comma-separated listing of everything you want to export from your module. Now, there's a problem there because Haskell really has two languages with symbols that may have the same name. This is particularly common with `newtype`s like the one in your example: you have a *type-level name* `SharedSeed :: *`, and also a value-level name (data constructor) `SharedSeed :: ByteString -> SharedSeed`.

This only happens with *uppercase* names, because lowercase at type level are always local type variables. Thus the convention in export lists that *uppercase names refer to types*.

But just exporting the type does not allow users to actually *construct values of that type*. That's often prudent: not all internal-representation values might make legal values of the newtype (see [Bartek's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45460153/745903)), so then it's better to only export a safe *smart constructor* instead of the unsafe data constructor.

But other times, you do want to make the data constructor available, certainly for multi-constructor types like `Maybe`. To that end, export lists have three syntaxes you can use:

```
module Pos.Core.Types(
```

- `SharedSeed (SharedSeed)` will export the constructor `SharedSeed`. In this case that's of course the only constructor anyway, but if there were other constructors they would *not* be exported with this syntax.
- `SharedSeed (..)` will export *all* constructors. Again, in this case that's only `SharedSeed`, but for e.g. `Maybe` it would export both `Nothing` and `Just`.
- `pattern SharedSeed` will export `ShareSeed` as a *standalone pattern* (independent of the export of the `ShareSeed` type). This requires the [`-XPatternSynonyms` extension](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PatternSynonyms).

  ```
  )
  ```